# Opening Google Maps inside a Partial View with JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, google-maps-api-3, partial-views

I am trying to display Google Maps inside a Partial View with JSON.  I have already tried the code inside a normal view and it works perfectly fine.

I have the following:-

Partial View ShowMap.cshtml

```
@using Microsoft.Web.Helpers

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<div class="experienceRestrictedText">
    @Maps.GetGoogleHtml("1, Redmond Way, Redmond, WA", width: "400", height: "400")
</div>
```

Index.cshtml (where the Partial view is launched)

```
    $('.modal_link_map').on('click', function (e) {
        $('.modal_part').show();
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var context = $('#tn_select').load('/Experience/ShowMap?id=' + id, function () {
            initSelect(context);
        });
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
```

And the controller Action is as follows:-

```
        public ActionResult ShowMap()
        {
        _ItemID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);

        viewModel.ExperienceViewModel.Experience =     unitOfWork.ExperienceRepository.GetByID(_ItemID);

        return PartialView(viewModel);
        }
```

Do I need to include anything else for this map to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not familiar with the `@Maps.GetGoogleHtml` helper but I am afraid that somehow this helper is including the following script:

```
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Except that this script cannot be loaded asynchronously because it uses `document.write()` to load the actual API. To make this work you should specify a `callback` parameter. Here's how your partial could look like:

```
<div class="experienceRestrictedText">
    <script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), { zoom: 14, center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.652437, -122.132424), mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId['ROADMAP'] });
            new google.maps.Geocoder().geocode({ address: '1, Redmond Way, Redmond, WA' }, function (response, status) {
                if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var best = response[0].geometry.location;
                    map.panTo(best);
                    new google.maps.Marker({ map: map, position: best });
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
    <div class="map" id="map" style="width:400px; height:400px;"></div>
</div>
```

Notice how a callback parameter is passed to the `http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js` script and the actual initialization of the maps is done inside this callback.

Also notice that I have removed the jquery script from the partial. I guess that jQuery is already loaded in your layout because you seem to be using it to attach to a `.on()` handler.

As an alternative you could have included the `<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>` in your main view but once you load the partial, the 
`@Maps.GetGoogleHtml` helper would have included it a second time.

Personally I am not a big fan of those kind of helpers because they are completely obscuring the underlying calls leaving you without much control and understanding of what's happening.

Comment: Hi Darin, yes this works.  How can I change the address to pass a dynamic one from my Model?

Comment: Pretty easily. You a string property in your model that you will populate inside the controller action and then simply make your partial view strongly typed to this view model and use the value from the model: `{ address: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Address)) }` that is passed to the `geocode` function.

Comment: Excellent!  I tried @Html.Raw(Model.Address) and it did not work, that is why I asked.  Thanks a lot, everything is working fine now!

Comment: Did you read my comment? `@Html.Raw(Model.Address)` is wrong and very unsafe. Never use anything like that. You should use `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Address))` if you want to correctly encode the value.

Comment: Hi Darin, I did, and that is why I have changed it to Json.Encode!  Did not know about this before.